# How do I see the name of the label?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a code like this:

```py
# Import label encoder
from sklearn import preprocessing

# label_encoder object knows how to understand word labels.
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# Encode labels in column 'species'.
df['Thematic  Subthematic'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['Thematic  Subthematic'])

data_labels = df['Thematic  Subthematic'].unique()
print(data_labels)
```

[image: Code image of labelencoder]

How can I see the name of that label?
eg: in my data `0` is a `cat`, `1` is a `dog` how do I print those names after using the label encoder?

Comment: please don't post image of code. Use the code formatting and post it as text

Answer (score 0):

- You can get mapping of label in `numpy.ndarray` from `classes_` attribute of `label_encoder`.
- In your case you can get mapping of label from `label_encoder.classes_`. Which will return `numpy.ndarray` in same sequence as it's mapped to `0, 1, 2, ...` respectively according to it's index position.
- You can refer to official documentation of [`LabelEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Comment: I need to see the names of the sequence.

Comment: ? Do you want to return the exact label? then you can just pass it as `label_encoder.classes_[INDEX]` where Index is the output/target variable which will return the correct label.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions (such as this one, including images of code instead of an MREhttps://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)), as advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)